# Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") become 1 instead of 0 in new PC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi there I am having a problem with an old project in this project there are 4 players means 4 horizontal axis's now the issue is the player drift to the left or right when the game starts. I solved the issue of the drift by changing the sensitivity to 1 now game runs perfectly with the Xbox controller but the issue is with the simple 1 - handle joysticks whenever i play with them on the first run of build the Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") is 0 by default but when I use the same built-in any other system the Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") becomes 1 so i have to change it every time on the startup input controlles. All i want to make the Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") zero by default whenever the game starts is there any way sorry for a long paragraph. This is the pic of the input manager and the code for the firstpersonController.
[image: Input Manager screen]

```
public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private float walkSpeed = 15.0f;
public LayerMask groundedMask;

public bool grounded;
[SerializeField]
Vector3 moveAmount;
[SerializeField]
Vector3 smoothMoveVelocity = Vector3.zero;
float verticalLookRotation;
Transform cameraTransform;
Rigidbody rigidbody;
public float inputX;


//for testing
[SerializeField] public Vector3 moveDir;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 targetMoveAmount;

void Start(){
    
}

void Awake() {
    walkSpeed = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("VolumeLevel");
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}

void Update()
{
    inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    moveDir = new Vector3 (-inputX, 0, 0).normalized;
    targetMoveAmount = moveDir * walkSpeed;
    moveAmount = Vector3.SmoothDamp (moveAmount, targetMoveAmount, ref smoothMoveVelocity, 0.15f);

    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
    RaycastHit hit;
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1 + .1f, groundedMask)) {
        grounded = true;
    }
    else {
        grounded = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed space");
        //rigidbody.velocity += new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
        rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(500, 0, 0));
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Apply movement to rigidbody
    if (!GravityBody.controllerStopped)
    {
        Vector3 localMove = transform.TransformDirection(moveAmount) * Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + localMove);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd made a change to InputActions from old Input. You can keep Input working in case you have it in many other places. It's simpler to setup for one player and reuse same Actions for other players on different gamepads. Give it a try.

Comment: isnt it something i can do which make unity to set the value of horizontal axis 0 whenver the game start

Comment: I have solved this problem a couple years ago by wrapping a controller input class around the Unity input class. It includes behavior where one gets 0 for an axis when it is not initialized.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`